# troubleshooting export command

Tags: linux, environment-variables, export

### Seems 'export' is not working.

```
HISTSIZE=66
export HISTSIZE
echo $HISTSIZE
66
```

Then in a new terminal,

```
echo $HISTSIZE
1000
```

Tried from user and from root. Shouldn't 'export' mean this variable is set in every shell environment until changed again with 'export' ?

```
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2020.2

type export
export is a shell builtin

echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: export only affects child processes started from the shell where you exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export` exports a variable visible only by the processes that run in that specific shell after the `export` command execution.
You can export global variables using /etc/profile.d for example. [Check out a relevant topic](https://serverfault.com/a/431614/345905).

Answer (score 0):

**If you frequently use the `export variables` then simply add the export command to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` if you are using zsh.**

- nano ~/.bashrc
- Append  `HISTSIZE=66 export HISTSIZE` to the end of the file and save it.
- Now it will work on every new terminal.